# How do I reset my keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: interface, customization

By accident I added left mouse click as a shortcut for toggling fullscreen for the active window. That won't allow me to get back into user preferences to rechange it. Is there any other way to change keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 4):

This shouldn't affect anything if you're clicking directly on buttons but you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to bring up your user preferences or press <kbd>Space</kbd> and search for it there. Next go to the Input tab and look for a button next to *Window* marked *Restore* *(Blender remembers what changes you make and offers a handy way to reset only that section without messing up any other keybindings you remapped)*. From there you can use to set it back to the default value of whatever config preset you are using.

If you have nothing to lose you can also bring up the space menu and type load factory settings then save that as your new startup settings.

Comment: I feel dumb now there is a so much easier solution. The going to the user preferences solution won't work though since it is impossible to navigate through the user preferences window without a mouse.

Comment: I added toggle fullscreen to my left click and this works for me.

Answer (score 3):

On the main menu:

File -> Defaults -> Load Factory Settings

This will reset all preferences.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to restore the factory settings.

**command prompt**

Open a command prompt, (press the windows key + <kbd>R</kbd> on windows, type "cmd" and press enter if you're using Windows) and navigate to the folder in which you installed blender by typing "cd .." to go to a parent directory, "cd [name]" to open a folder and "dir" to display the possible folders. Now type "blender.exe --factory-startup". Blender will open and you should be able to change and save the settings.

**blender wiki**

The blender wiki gives two other ways to restore the factory settings.

> 1. Go to File Load Factory Settings and then save the preferences with CtrlU or via the User Preferences editor.
> 2. Delete the startup.blend file from the following location on your computer:
>          Linux: /home/$user/.blender/'Version Number'/config/startup.blend (you'll need to show hidden files).
>          Windows 7 and Windows Vista: C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\'Version
>      Number'\config\startup.blend
>          MacOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Blender/'Version Number'/config/startup.blend (you'll need to
>      show hidden files, or press "command shift g" in a finder window, and input the path).

Comment: Here's why I DV'd. While this is an acceptable answer, and it's fairly easy to read, you aren't showing much effort. Your last paragraph shows displays this. While I don't think you should have lost your settings, you should have at least looked into how to maintain them (hint: look at the second paragraph from the Blender Wiki). And also, this isn't worth a DV on it's own, but is worth mentioning and does add up, you *need* to to post your source when you quote things. I don't care that it's in the Blender Manual. I need to be able to click a link and see what you quoted in the page.